# android wear build-in app minimum version

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm currently building an android wear application (API 20) as a module of my main application already published on the play store. My main app is using the Google Cardboard SDK for Unity3D. I've released this app on the play store with the minimum sdk set to API 16 (Jelly Bean).

My question is : if I package my wear app inside the APK of my main app with Android Studio, should I increase the minimum sdk to API 20 (Android Wear) in the main build.gradle ? I don't want to restrict my main app for API 20+ users only.

I've tested this configuration with my phone on kitkat and my Moto 360 on lollipop : no error occurred with the different build versions in the build.gradle files and both applications worked very well.

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No way. You have to set API 20 for your wear module and keep 16 for your main application.